# confused with BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

i have the following pgm which responds with a Toast with an incoming msg and also speaks out the received msg, however there seems to be no speech synthesis in background but i still can see the Toast though, so should i start a service from the onReceive method (don't know if that's possible) here and then in the startService method  , write the speak method??

here's one of my pgms:

**Receiver**

```
package com.example.TextSpeaker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


public static String str;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Log.d("Receiver","Message received successfully");

    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if(bundle!=null)
    {
        // retrive the sms received

        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i=0;i<msgs.length;i++)
        {
            str="";
            msgs[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            str+="Message From "+msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress()+".   ";
            str+="The message is "+msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            //TextSpeaker.mtts.speak(Receiver.str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            //str="";

        }
        Toast.makeText(context,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        TextSpeaker.mtts.speak(Receiver.str, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Intent serviceintent = new Intent();
> serviceintent.setAction(".SpeakerService");
> ```

I guess using the following change in your intent might help:

> ```
> Intent serviceintent = new Intent(context, SpeakerService.class)
> ```

Comment: thanks it worked! but again, though i am seeing in the log that service started but i can't hear any sound, does the tts engine run in background at all?

Comment: AKAIK yes, the tts engine keeps running in the background... and if its not showing any error in your log, i guess this means its working fine... By the way are you trying to use it on emulator or device??

Answer (score 1):

You need to give enough time for TTS service to start before you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea about starting the service in onReceive() and handling the speech output in the service should work. I would do the same. But I'm rather new to android programming.